# Explanation of OCaml code: explode a string, split a list

Tags: list, recursion, pattern-matching, ocaml

I am absolute OCaml beginner and have an assignment about more code. I have got the following code, but I don't know how it works. If someone can help me out, I appreciate it.

```
# let explode str =  (*defines function that explodes argument str witch is type
                       string into list of chars*)
  let rec exp = function    (*defines recursive function exp*)
    | a, b when a < 0 -> b  (*this part i dont know.is this pattern 
                              matching ?is it function with arguments a and b
                              and they go into expression? when is a guard and 
                              then we have if a is smaller than 0 then b *)
 (*if a is not smaller than 0 then this function ? *)
    | a, b -> exp (a-1, str.[a]::b) (*this i dont know, a and b are arguments
                                      that go into recursive function in the way
                                      that a is decreesed by one and b goes into
                                      string a?? *)
  in         
  exp ((String.length str)-1, []);; (*defined function exp on string lenght of
                                      str decresed by one (why?)  [ ]these
                                      brackets mean or tell some kind of type ? *)

# let split lst ch =
  let rec split = function  (* defines recursive fun split *)
    | [], ch, cacc', aacc' -> cacc'::aacc'(* if empty ...this is about what i got
                                             so far :) *)
    | c::lst, ch, cacc', aacc' when c = ch -> split (lst, ch, [], cacc'::aacc')
    | c::lst, ch, cacc', aacc' -> split (lst, ch, c::cacc', aacc')
  in
  split (lst, ch, [], []);;

val split : 'a list -> 'a -> 'a list list = <fun>
```

Comment: Why don't you start by adding comments to the code to explain what you  already understand of it and indicate those parts you don't understand?

Answer (score 4):

This code is ugly. Whoever has been giving that to you is making you a disservice. If a student of mine wrote that, I would ask them to rewrite them without using `when` conditionals, because they tend to be confusing, encourage to write pattern-matching-heavy code at places where they are not warranted.
As a rule of the thumb, beginners should never use `when`. A simple `if..then..else` test provides an increase in readability.

Here are equivalent versions of those two functions, rewritten for readability:

```
let explode str =
  let rec exp a b =
    if a < 0 then b
    else exp (a - 1) (str.[a] :: b)
  in
  exp (String.length str - 1) []

let split input delim_char =
  let rec split input curr_word past_words =
    match input with
      | [] -> curr_word :: past_words
      | c :: rest ->
        if c = delim_char
        then split rest [] (curr_word :: past_words)
        else split rest (c :: curr_word) past_words
  in
  split input [] []
```

My advice to understand them is to run them yourself, on a given example, on paper. Just write down the function call (eg. `explode "foo"` and `split 'b' ['a';'b';'c';'d']`), expand the definition, evaluate the code to get another expression, etc., until you get to the result. Here is an example:

```
explode "fo"
=>
exp (String.length "fo" - 1) []
=>
exp 1 []
=>
if 1 < 0 then [] else exp 0 ("fo".[1] :: [])
=>
exp 0 ("fo".[1] :: [])
=>
exp 0 ('o' :: [])
=>
exp 0 ['o']
=>
if 0 < 0 then ['o'] else exp (-1) ("fo".[0] :: ['o'])
=>
exp (-1) ("fo".[0] :: ['o'])
=>
exp (-1) ('f' :: ['o'])
=>
exp (-1) ['f'; 'o']
=>
if -1 < 0 then ['f'; 'o'] else exp (-2) ("fo".[-1] :: ['o'])
=>
['f'; 'o']
```

Take the care to do that, for each function, and any function you will have problem understanding. On a small example. That's the best way to get a global view of what's going on.

(Later when you grow more used to recursion, you'll find out that you don't actually need to do that, you can reason inductively on the function: make an assumption on what they do, and assuming that recursive calls actually do that, check that it indeed does it. In more advanced cases, trying to hold all the execution in one's head is just too hard, and this induction technique works better, but it is more high-level and requires more practices. First begin by simply running the code.)

Comment: Thank you for your answers you are very kind. I will do know what you suggested

Answer (score 1):

If you're using the Core library you can just use

```
String.to_list "BKMGTPEZY"
```

Which will return a list of `chars` if you want strings just `map` it:

```
String.to_list "BKMGTPEZY" |> List.map ~f:Char.to_string
```

Outputs:

```
- : bytes list = ["B"; "K"; "M"; "G"; "T"; "P"; "E"; "Z"; "Y"]
```

As a function

```
let explode s = String.to_list s |> List.map ~f:Char.to_string
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also implement in this way.

```
let rec strexp s  =  
  if length(s)==0 then 
   []
  else
  (strexp (sub s 0 (length(s)-1)))@(s.[length(s)-1]::[])    
;;
```